# ObservableCollection doesnt virtualise data?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, observablecollection

I want to add approx 600 images to my collection to show them in a Listview that virtualizes with Itemsstackpanel. If i didnt misread with virtualization its possible to load large datasets. My problem is that the collection can only hold around 150 images and then i get a OutOfMemory Exception. **Is there something more to enable virtualization or is the problem that my Collection calls its propertyChanged Event for every image added?**

The error is thrown on:

```
 await pdfPage.RenderToStreamAsync(Imagestream);
```

and how i add to my collection:

```
for (uint i = convertedPageString; i < 200 + convertedPageString; i++)
        {
            Image img = await LoadPage(l_document, i);              
            collection.Add(img);
            g_rootPage.ListViewControl.ItemsSource = collection;

        }
```

**convertedPageString is just the Page im starting on when the program is opened.**

**EDIT:**

This is my function to get the Pages.

```
public async Task<Image> LoadPage(PdfDocument a_document, uint page)
    {

        Image l_image;
        BitmapImage l_bitmap;
        PdfPage pdfPage;

        using (IRandomAccessStream Imagestream = new MemoryStream().AsRandomAccessStream())
        {
            using (pdfPage = a_document.GetPage(page))
            {
                
               await pdfPage.RenderToStreamAsync(Imagestream);


            
               l_bitmap = new BitmapImage();
               await l_bitmap.SetSourceAsync(Imagestream);
               l_image = new Image();

                l_bitmap.DecodePixelHeight = 1200;
                l_bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 1000;

                
                l_image.Source = l_bitmap;
               
                l_image.Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 10);
               
            }
        }

        return l_image; 
    }
```

I forgot to mention that i open the application via the commandLine with a specified page and path.

Comment: This is called [data virtualization](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization). As opposed WPF list controls supports *UI virtualization*

Comment: `ObservableCollection` is used to notify the UI when a collection item changes, and it does not have the capability of virtualization. Judging from your error message, it is the reason why a large number of pictures are loaded. Can you provide the complete picture loading code? And have you tried to use `new BitmapImage(new Uri(uriString))` as `Image.Source` instead of reading each image when loading?